# No se ejecuta fichero js en sitio hecho con Drupal7

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, drupal7

sencillo problema. Ejecuto este código

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("form#user_register_form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Submit prevented");
    });

});
```

En un fichero javascript para un sitio hecho en Drupal 7 y no funciona, no se muestra la alerta al enviar el formulario.

Me aseguré ya de que el fichero js fuera incluido.

El HTML del formulario es generado automáticamente por Drupal y me aseguré que su id es user-register-form y que el botón es de tipo submit y que está dentro de las etiquetas del form.

Comment: Hola Rory, bienvenido a [es.so]. Añadiste [tag:jquery] a tu pagina? a parte de eso, te salen mensajes de error en la consola? (pulsa F12). Mientras, lee el [tour] para aprender más de este sitio. Un saludo

Comment: @Rory, por favor, puedes poner el código HTML del formulario y el botón? Gracias!!!

Comment: El HTML del formulario es generado automáticamente por Drupal y me aseguré que su id es user-register-form y que el botón es de tipo submit y que está dentro de las etiquetas del form. Gracias.

Comment: puedes añadir un `console.log("Hola");` por ejemplo al `$document.ready` y así saber si al menos si $(jquery) está funcionando?

Comment: Lo añadí como me dijo y no se muestra el Hola en la consola. Lo que me resulta asombroso es que hay otros ficheros js dentro del mismo sitio que sí trabajan bien.

Comment: comprobaste entonces si en la consola sale algún error de $document.ready command not found o algo parecido?

Comment: Terminé por copiar el código directamente en el head del fichero html.tpl.php y así funcionó. Aún no entiendo por qué desde un fichero js aparte no lo reconoce. De hecho me está pasando ahora mismo con otro fichero javascript que quiero incluir para el vínculo "read more" pero este ni siquiera funciona cuando lo ejecuto en el head. Gracias por la ayuda.